# Getting ratio of summed columns

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following DB structure.

| id | projectname | number | filename | type | unq | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | prj1 | 2 | a | t1 | 888389f661e117 | 1 |
| 9 | prj1 | 2 | a | t1 | 888389f661e117 | 2 |
| 10 | prj1 | 2 | a | t1 | 888389f661e117 | 2 |
| 11 | prj1 | 2 | a | t2 | 816418549711c3d33 | 6 |
| 12 | prj1 | 2 | a | t2 | 816418549711c3d33 | 7 |
| 13 | prj1 | 2 | a | t2 | 816418549711c3d33 | 1 |
| 14 | prj1 | 2 | a | t3 | NULL | NULL |
| 15 | prj1 | 2 | a | t3 | NULL | NULL |
| 16 | prj1 | 2 | a | t3 | NULL | NULL |
| 17 | prj1 | 36 | b | t1 | 8dac5bdffc7f86502 | 0 |
| 18 | prj1 | 36 | b | t1 | 8dac5bdffc7f86502 | 0 |
| 19 | prj1 | 36 | b | t1 | 8dac5bdffc7f86502 | 0 |

I use the query below to get the sums of `count` column w.r.t. the `type` column. A unique identifier of a row is `(projectname, number, filename).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (projectname, number, type) number, type, SUM(count) as count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY (projectname, number, type)
ORDER BY number
```

which gives me the output

| number | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | t1 | 5 |
| 2 | t2 | 14 |
| 2 | t3 | NULL |
| 36 | t1 | 0 |
| 36 | t2 | 16 |
| 36 | t3 | NULL |

My ideal output is: for every `number` column item, I want to divide the `t2` value by `t1` and the `t3` value to `t2`. Can I accomplish this with Postgres commands without using external data manipulation techniques? I am looking to obtain a table as below. The `type` column is just representative of the operation I am interested in.

| number | type | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | t2t1 | 14 by 5 |
| 2 | t3t2 | NULL by 14 is NULL |
| 36 | t2t1 | 16 by 0 is INF |
| 36 | t3t2 | NULL by 16 is NULL |

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data

Comment: I added a representative table at the bottom @D-Shih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `which gives me the output` we can try to use  `LEAD` and `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get next `count` and filter the latest row each `number`

```
SELECT number,
       type,
       CASE WHEN count = 0 THEN 'INF' ELSE (n_count::DECIMAL(8,3) /count )::VARCHAR(20) END
FROM (
  SELECT *,
        LEAD(count) OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY type) n_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY type DESC) rn 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (projectname, number, type) number, type, SUM(count) as count
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY (projectname, number, type)
    ORDER BY number
  ) t1
) t1
WHERE rn > 1
```

but I saw full sample data and expect result you might need to use `OUTER JOIN` based on `type`,`number` which is created by `CROSS JOIN`

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT *
 FROM (
  SELECT distinct type
  FROM myTable
 ) t1 CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT distinct number
  FROM myTable
 ) t2
)
SELECT number,
       type,
        CASE WHEN count = 0 THEN 'INF' ELSE (n_count::DECIMAL(8,3) /count )::VARCHAR(20) END
FROM (
  SELECT *,
        LEAD(count) OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY type) n_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY type DESC) rn 
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.number, t1.type, SUM(t2.count) count
    FROM CTE t1
    LEFT JOIN myTable t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type
    AND t1.number = t2.number
   GROUP BY t1.number, t1.type
  ) t1
) t1
WHERE rn > 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=900dcd8b95055989df2e89a7b3829ea1)

Comment: Both of the answers look great. I appreciate your effort @D-Shih. They work! I will study each item of the queries which are a lot beyond my knowledge. Thanks a lot.